# How to avoid treating a NULL value as the minimum value in data comparison?

Tags: null, comparison, dolphindb

For example, Now it returns “True” for NULL< 0.

But I want to return “NULL True False” when NULL -1 1<0. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you can set configuration parameter `nullAsMinValueForComparison` to ‘false’.

For more details, refer to [configuration] page. The `nullAsMinValueForComparison` parameter indicates whether a NULL value is treated as the minimum value in data comparison. The default value is true. If it is set to “false”, the result of comparison involving NULL value is NULL.

Comment: Did you mean to give a link for the `[configuration]` page? Or maybe show an image?

Answer (score 0):

```
nullCompare(<, NULL -1 1, 0)
```